# Moments of Method Estimators of $\operatorname{Bi}(n,p)$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, binomial-distribution

So I need to find MME for $p$ when $X\sim \operatorname{Bi}(n,p)$.
$$\operatorname{E}[X] = np$$
$$\operatorname{Var}(X) = np(1-p)$$
I first divided $\operatorname{Var}(X)$ and $\operatorname{E}[X]$ to eliminate $n$.
$$\frac{\operatorname{Var}(X)}{\operatorname{E}[X]} = 1-p$$

To solve: $\operatorname{E}[X] = \bar{x}$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X) = \frac{1}{n}\sum x_i^2 - \frac{1}{n}\bar{x}^2$.

But now I am currently stuck at:

$$p=1-\left(\frac{\sum x_i^2-\bar{x}^2}{n\bar{x}}\right).$$

How can I eliminate $n$?

Comment: If you have a bunch of sample points, you know how many sample points you have, and so you could just plug in $n$.  Alternatively, $n\bar{x}$ is just $\sum x_i$.

Comment: @cronky I think it is better to denote n of parameter and n of size differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be careful to define what constitutes your sample.

For instance, suppose you are observing a sequence of independent and identically distributed (iid) **binomial** random variables, say $X_1, X_2, X_3, \ldots$, each of which has the same distribution $$X_i \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n, p).$$  Then the sample size does not necessarily equal the parameter $n$, since you could potentially observe many more data; e.g., your sample could be $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_m$.  Then the sample mean and (bias-uncorrected) sample variance $$\bar X = \frac{1}{\color{red}{m}} \sum_{i=1}^{\color{red}{m}} X_i, \quad \varsigma^2 = \frac{1}{\color{red}{m}} \sum_{i=1}^{\color{red}{m}} \left( X_i - \bar X\right)^2 \tag{1}$$ are calculated for that sample size $m$, and a method of moments estimator for $p$ would be $$\tilde p = 1 - \frac{\varsigma^2}{\bar X} = 1 - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^m (X_i - \bar X)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^m X_i}. \tag{2}$$  There is no $n$ in this expression.  Note that we must have $m > 1$ for $(2)$ to be of any value, since the sample variance is $0$ if $m = 1$.

On the other hand, if what you are observing is a sequence of $n$ iid **Bernoulli** random variables, say $B_1, B_2, \ldots, B_n$, with $$B_i \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(p),$$ then in effect the statistic $$X = \sum_{i=1}^n B_i \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n,p)$$ is a single binomial variable.  The method of moments estimator must now be calculated for the Bernoulli sample; i.e.

$$\operatorname{E}[B_i] = p, \quad \operatorname{Var}[B_i] = p(1-p),$$

hence you could write

$$\tilde p = 1 - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (B_i - \bar B)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n B_i}. \tag{3}$$  But this is not necessary:  you already have with the first moment

$$\tilde p = \bar B$$  and there is no need to use the sample variance.